# Why is JavaScript private method accessible from console.log

Tags: javascript, class, google-chrome-devtools, private-members, private-methods

I wrote a simple code:

```
const secure = new class {
    #privateProperty = 4;
    #privateMethod() {
        console.log( 'The property ' + this.#privateProperty + ' should not be accessible outside this class' );
    }
}
```

If it is immediately followed by the syntax below

`secure.#privateMethod();`

I get an error which says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#privateMethod' must be declared in an enclosing class`

However, If I don't immediately call the `secure.#privateMethod()` and then go to developer tool - console and write the syntax there, it outputs:

`The property 4 should not be accessible outside this class`

Is there a special reason why this is happening?

Comment: That's because you're accessing the private method within the class

Comment: What developer tools are you using? Chrome devtools? VSCode debugger?

Comment: I am using Chrome Dev Tool.

Comment: Why wouldn't a debugger allow invoking private methods?

Comment: @Bergi - I was assuming some cases where a private method is required to be called only once and invoking those private method on debugger will make it call twice or more. I tested the above code as well on Firefox v111.0 and it gave an error in the debugger. But chrome and Edge doesn't give error

Comment: @Bergi - I believe a debugger should not invoke private method because (1): It is `private` and accessing it outside it's class defies the purpose of it's privacy. (2): Private method are most times used to run code that a developer does not want others to access probably to avoid displaying some (non-sensitive) information, but debugger will display it. There are many more reasons but this comment section allows limited character to type...

Comment: It's a debugger. It can do anything it wants to your code - rewrite it, skip it, make it public. Of course it will display private fields, how would the developer be supposed to debug them otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug! [New in the devtools of Chrome 111](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-111/#misc):

> To better facilitate debugging, DevTools now supports evaluating expressions with private class members. ([1381806](https://crbug.com/1381806))
>
> [image]

This is very useful when developing classes with private fields. You no longer need to put a breakpoint in a class method to be able to run code that accesses (gets, sets, invokes) private fields.