# Private class field '#foo' is public in Chrome Version 122.0.6261.112 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Tags: javascript

The fourth logging in my chrome is "test".

Chrome Version 122.0.6261.112 (Official Build) (x86_64).

I'm not sure about if I configured some flags or extensions of chrome.

> Code from the answer of [Private properties in JavaScript ES6 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156326/private-properties-in-javascript-es6-classes)

```js
class Something {
  #property;

  constructor(){
    this.#property = "test";
  }

  #privateMethod() {
    return 'hello world';
  }

  getPrivateMessage() {
      return this.#property;
  }
}

const instance = new Something();
console.log(instance.property); //=> undefined
console.log(instance.privateMethod); //=> undefined
console.log(instance.getPrivateMessage()); //=> test
console.log(instance.#property); //=> It should be syntax error but test
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Using the Chrome console?

Comment: That will only "work" (that is, allow the invalid access) in the browser console in devtools. **Don't use the browser console to test conceptual things** (or if you do, verify in a real environment), it's a non-standard environment that does several things differently from a real environment in order to facilitate debugging. If you run the Stack Snippet I've copied your code into (or just run the code in any other normal way), you'll see the error.

Comment: Most likely answered here if you're executing it in your browser console: [Why is JavaScript private method accessible from console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75837140)

Comment: Please don't post and run. When you post a question or answer, please *stick around* for a few minutes so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments. But in this case, we can be sure you're either using the browser console or using a transpiler that doesn't correctly raise an error. Chrome itself -- which is to say, V8 -- definitely does correctly implement private fields and therefore disallow the access above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, Chrome console allows access to private fields for debugging purposes.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-111/#misc